# Marginal plots interpretation via the rasterVis package in R

Tags: raster, r

I have two `landcover` classifications computed via `random forest` and `maximum likelihood classification` models. Then I used the `rasterVis::levelplot` to see the difference between the two. The results can be seen below. My question is what is the information being conveyed by these two `marginal plots`?

[image]

Histogram of difference between the classification rasters:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margins are controlled by the margin parameter - ?rasterVis::levelplot tells you:

```
 margin: A list or a logical. If it is TRUE, two marginal graphics
          show the column (x) and row (y) summaries of the ‘Raster*’
          object. The summary is computed with the function ‘mean’. 
          [etc]
```

So by default it shows the mean of each row and column. You can change it to show, for example, the min or max value in each column:

```
> levelplot(r,margin=list(FUN=min))
> levelplot(r,margin=list(FUN=max))
```

Note it doesn't plot the axes so you can't tell the values so its only good for checking relative summary values across that dimensions of the raster.